# If an integral domain is ordered, is its field of fractions ordered?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, integral-domain

Let $R$ be an integral domain such that there is a total ordering of it. If $F$ is its field of fractions, is there a total ordering on $F$? In particular, is it naturally induced by that of $R$?

Comment: Did you try the obvious thing where $a/b$ is positive when $a$ and $b$ are positive?

Answer (score 1):

Say $\frac ab$ is positive if $ab$ is positive. Show that this is well-defined. Show that the sum and product of two positive fractions is positive. Show that the fractions are partitioned into positives, 0, and the additive inverses of positives.